# Pyspark graphframes - connectedcomponents with partitioned vertex

Tags: python, pyspark, graphframes

I want to make a network using connectedComponents.
My vertex and edge dataframes look like below:

```
vertex = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', 1),
        ('a', 2),
        ('a', 3),
        ('b', 1),
        ('b', 5),
        ('b', 6),
        ('b', 7),
        ('b', 8),
        ('b', 3),
        ('c', 2),
        ('c', 3)
    ],['property', 'id'])

edge = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1,2),
        (2,3),
        (1,5),
        (5,6),
        (6,7),
        (7,8),
        (5,6)
    ],['src', 'dst'])
```

I create GraphFrame with vertex and edge, and run connectedComponents but all ids have same component.
What I need is separate component value for each "property" value:

```
 result.show()
 +---------+---+---------+
 |property | id|component|
 +---------+---+---------+
 |        a|  1|        1|
 |        a|  2|        1|
 |        a|  3|        1|
 |        b|  1|        2|
 |        b|  5|        2|
 |        b|  6|        2|
 |        b|  7|        2|
 |        b|  8|        2|
 |        b|  3|        3|
 |        c|  2|        4|
 |        c|  3|        4|
 +---------+---+---------+
```

I have some silly idea that I can make the result by executing connectedComponents for each property using for loop. But real vertex data is very large size(`countDistinct('property')` shows over 30M. ), and using for loop seems very inefficient.
Is there any other way to do this?